# Javascript replace space to dash except space before and after a dash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to modify a string using javascript. I should replace all of whitespace to `-`, except the space is before or after a dash.

For example:

```
const url= 'This is an - url';
let newUrl = url.replace(/\s+/g,'-');
let newUrlLowerCase = newUrl.toLowerCase();
```

it's give me result `this-is-an---url`, what I need is `this-is-an-url`

How do I can do that with javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can match a space *or* a dash, in a character set, and repeat it, replacing with a single dash:

```js
const url = 'This is an - url';
let newUrl = url.replace(/[\s-]+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
console.log(newUrl);
```

Comment: Better than my solution ++

Comment: @anubhava is that's yours that has been removed?

Comment: Yes that was mine.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the `-` with `' '` before space replace

```js
const url= 'This is an - url';
let newUrl = url.replace('-',' ').replace(/\s+/g,'-')
let newUrlLowerCase = newUrl.toLowerCase();
console.log(newUrlLowerCase)
```